# jquery function is not working?

Tags: jquery, forms, select

I have a select field. When the user selects option from the field, I want to display ouput as per user selection. Example if user select 2 then, I want to display 'hello world' two times. here is what I have done so far.

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 

 <p>Select Option:<select id="noAct">
       <option value="1">1</option>
       <option value="2">2</option>
       <option value="3">3</option>
       <option value="4">4</option
     </select>


<p id="tables"></p> 

<script>
    function displayTable()
    {
        var value = $("#noAct").val();

        //for loop to display the no of tables required
        for ( var i=0; i<value; i++ )
        {
            //display the table
            $("#tables").html("<b>Hello World</b>");

        }
    }

    $( "select" ).change( displayTable );
    displayTable();
</script>
```

I am getting no output or whatsoever. Can someone help me?

Comment: how about putting the `change` and `displayTable()` in a dom ready handler ?

Comment: Syntax errors, missing quotes on the `noAct` ID, unclosed option tags etc.

Comment: I am new to jquery so it would be great if you could asses me solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix the syntax errors, and use `append()` in the loop, not `html()` as it overwrites the content on each iteration

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 

<p>Select Option:</p>
<select id="noAct">
     <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="2">2</option>
     <option value="3">3</option>
     <option value="4">4</option>
</select>


<p id="tables"></p> 

<script>
    function displayTable() {
        var value = $("#noAct").val();

        $("#tables").empty();

        for ( var i=0; i < value; i++ ) {
            $("#tables").append("<b>Hello World</b><br />");
        }
    }

    $( "select" ).change( displayTable );
    displayTable();
</script>
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/PMYv2/)

Answer (score 0):

Try like below,

```
$(document).ready(function() {

     $( "select" ).change( displayTable );

});
```

Comment: The `$(document).ready(` is unnecessary and you're calling `displayTable()` and passing the return value (`undefined`) to `change` instead of a function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#noAct" ).on( 'change', function(){
        var value = $(this).val();

        //for loop to display the no of tables required
        $("#tables").html();
        for ( var i=0; i<value; i++ )
        {
            //display the table
            $("#tables").append("<b>Hello World</b><br />");

        }
    } );
});
</script>
```